# gbd fails to link to source

Tags: gdb, codeblocks

I'm having problems using gdb with codeblocks on windows. Using even the default console app with no changes, right after a fresh install of codeblocks, it stops at breakpoints but does not highlight the line in gdb. doesn't seem to know where to look.
Project path is C:\Users\username\Documents\codeblocks

Building with -g (default)

bt gives me this

```
#0  0x0009df38 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```